# Degree and Lefschetz number of a function

Tags: differential-geometry

I'd like to check if I got the following computation right.

Let $f:RP^3\rightarrow RP^3$ be given by $[x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3] \mapsto [x_0^2:x_1^2:x_2^2:x_3^2]$ I would like to compute the degree and the Lefschetz number of $f$.

$\boxed{\textrm{Degree}}$ In order to compute the degree we can pick any regular value $y$ of $f$ and compute $$deg(f)=deg(f;y)=\sum_{p\in f^{-1}(y)} sgn(D_pf)$$

In the chart $x_0\neq0$, the function $f$ has local expression $\bar{f}(\bar{x}_1,\bar{x}_2,\bar{x}_3)=(\bar{x}_1^2,\bar{x}_2^2,\bar{x}_3^2)$ so $D_pf=diag(2\bar{x}_1,2\bar{x}_2,2\bar{x}_3)$ and $(0,0,0)$ is the only regular value in this chart (i.e. [1:0:0:0]). In this case it is clear that $sgn(D_{[1:0:0:0]}f)=1$. Proceeding analogously with the other 4 charts we conclude that $deg(f)=4$.

$\boxed{\textrm{Lefschetz number}}$ The Lefschetz number is given by $$L(f)=\sum_{x\textrm{ fixed}} L_x(f)=\sum_{x\textrm{ fixed}} sgn(\det(d_xf-I))$$

The only fixed points of $f$ are those whose coordinates consist of 0's and 1's and we have 15 such points.

We have 4 fixed points with one non-zero coordinate. For instance, for $[1:0:0:0]$, working in the chart $x_0\neq0$ we have $\det(d_{(0,0,0)}f-I)=\det(diag(-1,-1,-1)=-1$

We have 6 fixed points with 2 non-zero coordinates and for each of these $\det(d_xf-I)=1$

We have 4 fixed points with 3 non-zero coordinates and for each of these $\det(d_xf-I)=-1$

Finally there is $[1:1:1:1]$ for which $\det(d_xf-I)=1$

Adding up all these local Lefschetz numbers we conclude that $L(f)=-4+6-4+1=-1$.

I'd be glad if someone could confirm whether or not these computations correct?

Comment: You're confusing singular value and regular value. Remember, moreover, that almost every value must be a regular value. So, start again, and you should find that a general regular value will have $8$ preimages. How do the signs work out?

Comment: Okay, I see. I'll type an edit in a moment. Is the computation of the Lefschetz number right?

Comment: Even easier, the map is clearly not surjective, so what must the degree be? Offhand, I don't see (yet) a flaw with your Lefschetz count, but algebraic topology tells us the answer should be $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The degree of the map is $0$ — the easiest way to see this is to observe that the map fails to be surjective, so any point (e.g., $[1,-1,1,1]$) not in the image is a regular value with no preimages.

The homological definition of the Lefschetz number tells us that the Lefschetz number will be $\lambda_f = 1 - \deg(f) = 1$. You are indeed correct that there are 15 (Lefschetz) fixed points. However, with the exception of $[1,1,1,1]$, there is an orientation discrepancy with the standard charts, which results in the other Lefschetz numbers' all cancelling in pairs. (Thanks to @MikeMiller for pointing this out to me.) For example, an easy computation shows that the standard charts $[1,x,y,z]$ and $[w,1,u,v]$ differ by an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism.